# Are the functions injective and surjective?

Tags: calculus, functions

I want to check if the following functions are injective and surjective.

1. $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, $x\mapsto \begin{cases}2x-1 & \text{ falls } x>0 \\ -2x & \text{ falls } x\leq 0\end{cases}$
2. $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \dfrac{x+y}{2}$

$$$$

I have done the following:

1. Let $x_1, x_2\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

   If $x_1, x_2>0$ then we have $2x_1-1=2x_2-1 \Rightarrow 2x_1=2x_2 \Rightarrow x_1=x_2$.

   If $x_1, x_2\leq 0$ then we have $-2x_1=-2x_2 \Rightarrow x_1=x_2$.

   So the function $f$ is injective.

   Let $y\in \mathbb{N}$ with $f(x)=y$.

   If $f(x)=2x-1$ then $2x-1=y \Rightarrow 2x=y+1 \Rightarrow x=\frac{y+1}{2}$.

   If $f(x)=-2x$ then $-2x=y \Rightarrow x=\frac{-y}{2}$.

   If $y$ is even then $\frac{-y}{2}\in \mathbb{Z}$ and so there is a $x\leq 0$ such that $f(x)=y$.

   If $y$ is odd then $y+1$ is even and so $\frac{y+1}{2}\in \mathbb{Z}$ and so there is a $x> 0$ such that $f(x)=y$.

   So for each $y\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $f(x)=y$.

   Therefore $f$ is surjective.

Is everything correct and complete?

2. Let $\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ y_1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}x_2 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $g\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ y_1\end{pmatrix}=g\begin{pmatrix}x_2 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix}$. Then $\frac{x_1+y_1}{2}=\frac{x_2+y_2}{2}$.

   It holds e.g. $g\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}=g\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ but $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\neq \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$.

   Therefore $g$ is not injective.

   Let $w\in \mathbb{R}$ with $g\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=w \Rightarrow \frac{x+y}{2}=w $.

   How can we continue to check the surjectivity?

Comment: For surjectivity of $g$, let $y\in\mathbb{R}$, than $g(0,2y) = 2y/2 = y$, so $g$ is surjective.

Comment: or take $g(y,y)=y$

Comment: For injectivity of $g$, it is generalizable that no continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ where $n>1$ is injective.

Comment: Please mark (nice) answers as accepted $\left( \color{limegreen}{\checkmark}\right)$. It would show that you appreciate effort  and the contribution of the answerer. Please check all your other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the proof of surjectivity of $f$ is generally correct, but not phrased very well, because you assumed $y \in \mathbb{N}$ with $f(x) = y$, when the existence of such an $x$ is what you're trying to prove.

For surjectivity of $f$, I would structure the proof as follows.

Let $y \in \mathbb{N}$

If $y$ is even, then let $x := \frac{-y}{2}$. $x$ is a nonpositive integer so $f(x) = y$.

If $y$ is odd then let $x := \frac{y+1}{2}$. Then $x$ is a positive integer and $f(x) = y$.

The non injectivity of $g$ proof is correct.
For surjectivity, if $w \in \mathbb{R}$ then $g\begin{pmatrix} w \\ w\end{pmatrix} = w$. There are other things that work as well, for example $g\begin{pmatrix} 2w \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = w$